# How to read multiline .properties file in python

Tags: python, properties, multiline

I'm trying to read a java multiline i18n properties file. Having lines like:

```
messages.welcome=Hello\
 World!
messages.bye=bye
```

Using this code:

```
import configobj
properties = configobj.ConfigObj(propertyFileName)
```

But with multilines values it fails.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [ConfigObj documentation](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/configobj.html#the-config-file-format), `configobj` requires you to surround multiline values in triple quotes:

> Values that contain line breaks
>   (multi-line values) can be surrounded
>   by triple quotes. These can also be
>   used if a value contains both types of
>   quotes. List members cannot be
>   surrounded by triple quotes:

If modifying the properties file is out of the question, I suggest using [configparser](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/configparser.html):

> In config parsers, values can span
>   multiple lines as long as they are
>   indented more than the key that holds
>   them. By default parsers also let
>   empty lines to be parts of values.

Here's a quick proof of concept:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

from __future__ import print_function

try:
    import ConfigParser as configparser
except ImportError:
    import configparser

try:
    import StringIO
except ImportError:
    import io.StringIO as StringIO

test_ini = """
[some_section]
messages.welcome=Hello\
 World
messages.bye=bye
"""
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.readfp(StringIO.StringIO(test_ini))
print(config.items('some_section'))
```

Output:

> [('messages.welcome', 'Hello World'),
>   ('messages.bye', 'bye')]

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the answers, this is what I finally did:

- Add the section to the fist line of the properties file
- Remove empty lines
- Parse with configparser
- Remove first line (section added in first step)

This is a extract of the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
...
# Add the section
subprocess.Popen(['/bin/bash','-c','sed -i \'1i [default]\' '+srcDirectory+"/*.properties"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
# Remove empty lines
subprocess.Popen(['/bin/bash','-c','sed -i \'s/^$/#/g' '+srcDirectory+"/*.properties"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
# Get all i18n files
files=glob.glob(srcDirectory+"/"+baseFileName+"_*.properties")
config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
for propFile in files:
...
    config.read(propertyFileName)
    value=config.get('default',"someproperty")
...
# Remove section 
subprocess.Popen(['/bin/bash','-c','sed -i \'1d\' '+srcDirectory+"/*.properties"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

I still have troubles with those multilines that doesn't start with an empty space. I just fixed them manually, but a sed could do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Format your properties file like this:

```
messages.welcome="""Hello
 World!"""
messages.bye=bye
```

Comment: This is a Java properties file, I can't modify them. Even if I use temporary files, formatting will be tough.

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to [ConfigParser](http://docs.python.org/library/configparser.html)

Comment: I already tried but it needs at least one Category something like [default].

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand anything in the Java broth, but a regex would help you, I hope:

```
import re

ch = '''messages.welcome=Hello
  World!  
messages.bye=bye'''

regx = re.compile('^(messages\.[^= \t]+)[ \t]*=[ \t]*(.+?)(?=^messages\.|\Z)',re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL)

print regx.findall(ch)
```

result

```
[('messages.welcome', 'Hello\n  World!  \n'), ('messages.bye', 'bye')]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. But my problem is to get the assignation from a text file, the parsing is OK

Comment: @ghm1014 Well, don't you know to read the content of a file and then to treat it in order to remove newlines and surrounding whitespaces, and other manipulations like that ?

Comment: Sure I could do in the hard way, but too many special cases may appear. Taking in count these are translation files for 12 languages and thousands of messages.