# Python 2.x - ConfigParser stripping blank lines in multiline value

Tags: python, configparser, blank-line

The following is the file parsed by [ConfigParser](http://docs.python.org/library/configparser.html):

```
[Ticket]
description = This is a multiline string.
 1
 2

 4
 5

 7
```

As described by the [official Python wiki for ConfigParser examples](http://wiki.python.org/moin/ConfigParserExamples), here is the helper function:

```
def ConfigSectionMap(section):
    dict1 = {}
    options = Config.options(section)
    for option in options:
        try:
            dict1[option] = Config.get(section, option)
            if dict1[option] == -1:
                DebugPrint("skip: %s" % option)
        except:
            print("exception on %s!" % option)
            dict1[option] = None
    return dict1
```

The resulting value is:

```
>>> print ConfigSectionMap('Ticket')['description']
This is a multiline string.
1
2
4
5
7
```

The expected value was:

```
>>> print ConfigSectionMap('Ticket')['description']
This is a multiline string.
1
2

4
5

7
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

**Update**: The link I gave you below was to Python 3.0, my apologies I forgot your tag.

The 2.7 docs do not mention blank lines in values, so I suspect they are not supported at all.

See also this SO question (which looks like Python 3): [How to read multiline .properties file in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5984603/how-to-read-multiline-properties-file-in-python)

---

From the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/configparser.html):

> Values can also span multiple lines, as long as they are indented
>   deeper than the first line of the value. Depending on the parser’s
>   mode, blank lines may be treated as parts of multiline values or
>   ignored.

I don't know what 'parser mode' this is referring to, but not sure if what you want is doable.

On the other hand, the docs also mention the `empty_lines_in_values` option, which seems to indicate that blank lines **are** supported.
Seems somewhat contradictory to me.

Comment: Thanks for this, but as you already realized, I am using Python 2.7.  There is no _empty_lines_in_values_ in ConfigParser for Python 2.7, unfortunately.

Comment: @ghee22: If you are not restricted to the standard library, you could use ConfigObj, as mentioned in the SO link I gave. You can use triple-quotes to surround values. Here's the docs: http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/configobj.html#the-config-file-format

Answer (score 0):

One way to fix it is to modify the helper function to:

```
def ConfigSectionMap(section):
    dict1 = {}
    options = Config.options(section)
    for option in options:
        try:
            dict1[option] = Config.get(section, option).replace('\\n', '')
            if dict1[option] == -1:
                DebugPrint("skip: %s" % option)
        except:
            print("exception on %s!" % option)
            dict1[option] = None
    return dict1
```